# jQuery Address - Content Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not able to get jQuery Address plugin working. I have an index page with a div like:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

I want its content to load dynamically with jQuery Address.
I also have a menu like:

```
<a href="portfolio.php" rel="address:/portfolio">portfolio</a>
<a href="curriculum.php" rel="address:/curriculum">curriculum</a></li>
```

My JS is:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $("#test").load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

And:

```
$.address.change(function(event){
    $("#test").load(event.value);
});
```

I was not able to do more than this. Is someone able to help me and explain me? The doc is very little..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used jquery address, but here is an example of somebody trying to do exactly what you were trying to do

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/state/

Comment: I have seen this, but the source code is TOTALLY different from the http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/#sample-usage

Comment: I think your problem is in your middle bit of code. when you 'a' is clicked, you need to pass some thing to $.address.value

Comment: perhaps $.address.value($(this).attr('href'));

Comment: Can you make me an example? I don't understand

Comment: could you put "console.log(event);" into your $.address.change function and see that things are getting passed to it appropriately?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22206/discussion-between-bostonjohn-and-wired)